# Modelling food in population dynamics

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

[image]

I understand that this model of food means that the amount of food available decreases as the population increases, however I do not understand the two  parts underlined in green. How do these agree with one another? Here I believe $F_0$ is $F$ at $t=0$, hence we must have $N(0)=0$

Comment: I don't know if I am missing anything but what is $N(t)$???

Comment: Population at time $t$, apologies

Comment: $F_0$ is the food avaliable with a population size of 0, not at time 0. Or simply as food decreases linearily the population size, it is the intercept of the straight line.

Comment: Your equation doesn't seems to be right, since the dimensional formula of the equation is not right. The term $eN(t)$ does not represent the unit of food and e represents the rate of consumption of food by a particular species per unit time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording is ambiguous but it makes sense if you take $F_0$ as the rate of food production, then $F(t)=F_0-eN(t)$ is the rate of growth in food stock at time $t$ corresponding to population $N(t)$. Then you will get a carrying capacity $N_{max}=F_0/e$, the population level at which all the food production is consumed.